# Calling a function with an if statement in C

Tags: c, function, if-statement

I have a program that works out the reduced mass of a molecule, and want to call that with an if function. This is the code I have at the moment:

```
int program ();
int main()
{
    printf("Press 1 to calculate the reduced mass of a molecule or press any other button to exit:");
    scanf ("%lg",&repeat);

    if(repeat==1)
    {
    program();
    }
    else
    {
    return(0);
    }
}

int program ()
//etc...
```

I'm not too experienced with C, so an explanation might be useful. Also would this make it so that you can repeat the function as many times as you like?

Comment: Lookup **conditional loops** in C. `while` or `for` or `do-while`.

Comment: Where is `repeat` defined?

Comment: This is not appropriate as a question here (if there is any). Please do a minimum of research on SO or the whole web before hand.

Comment: `int main()` was standard practice many years ago and became officially obsolete in 1989.  Use either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: `if()` is not function is flow-control construct in C. your program check the value of `repeat` is equal to `1` then calls a function `program();` that is defined some where in your code. If `repeat` is not equal to `1` then program terminates.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan that's exactly what i'm trying to do, but I cant make it work? is there anything you suggest to try?

Comment: @chemistryprograms `scanf ("%lg",&repeat);` does `repeat` used any where else in your code. show its declaration in code. Also what do you mean by '*it I cant make it work?*'.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan repeat is defined outside both functions as a global variable. And what i mean is that if i press 1 in the program it terminates, and the same if i press any other button

Answer (score 1):

If you begin in C, you could start by using the program (your compiled C) arguments. This way you can provide the program with *N* a number of times the `program()` function is to be called.

E.g.

```
   // Includes that have some library functions declarations
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   // argc and argc can be provided to the main function.
   // argv is an array of pointers to the arguments strings (starting from 0)
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      if (argc < 2) return 1; // argc number of parameters including the program name itself
      int repeat = atoi(argv[1]); // atoi convert a string to integer

      // repeat-- decrements repeat after its value was tested against 0 in the while
      while (repeat-- > 0) {
         program();
      }

      return 0;
   }
```

*argc* is tested against 2, since the program name itself is the 1st argument, you need at least 2, with N. E.g.

```
   ./myprog 5
```

will run *program()* 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

`I'm not too experienced with C, so an explanation might be useful.` 

Not sure what exactly you need an explanation of:

```
int program (); <-- function prototype for "program" defined here so you can call it in
int main()      <--  main. 
{
    // Display a message
    printf("Press 1 to calculate the reduced mass of a molecule or press any other button to exit:");
    // store the value typed by the user as a double, also it will accept scientific 
    // notation (that’s he g part). So you could enter 3.964e+2 if you wanted... an 
    // int or even a char would have been fine here
    scanf ("%lg",&repeat);
```

`Also would this make it so that you can repeat the function as many times as you like?`
No, that does not. First, it won't compile because there's no definition of "repeat"; second, you're missing a looping mechanism. `for`, `while`, `do/while`, recursion... whatever it maybe. Your code can be completed with an infinite loop pretty easily:

```
int main()
{
    double repeat = 0;
    for(;;) {
        printf("Press 1 to calculate the reduced mass of a molecule or press any other button to exit:");
        scanf ("%lg",&repeat);

        if(repeat==1)
        {
            program();
        }
        else
        {
            return(0);
        }
    }
}
```