# Call a function when a Boolean is true using the AND operator (&&)

Tags: javascript, c, boolean

In JavaScript you can call a function if a certain Boolean variable is true:

```
booleanVariable && functionToExecute();
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in C?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318859/calling-a-function-with-an-if-statement-in-c  this could be helpful

Comment: Seems like it would have taken less time to try this in a C program than it did to compose and post the question.

Comment: I obviously have... since I am running into this problem. I was thinking maybe there was a special syntax

Comment: Thank you kaumnen but that doesn't answer my question. You can call a function inside an if statement in any language. I was asking if there was a shorter way to do it and avoid having too many nested if statements. I guess this is not possible in C.

Comment: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/HIbRP3W1uil

Comment: Thank you Lee! Exactly what I was looking for. Needed to include the return statement.

Comment: Yes I was going to tell you to post it as an answer so I can mark it. Done!

Comment: @seddouguim "*I obviously have...*" how is that at all obvious? "*since I am running into this problem.*" There is no problem mentioned in your question. You just asked if it's possible. Not "I tried it but it didn't work." And speaking of trying "*I was thinking maybe there was a special syntax*" - what exactly did you try, given that the answer you accepted *shows the exact code as in the question*? What was the problem you had [that you decided to not ask about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Well by using a little deduction one can understand the the "problem" I was facing was that trying to run a function in the method mentioned above wasn't working. 

@pointy snarly remarked that it would have taken less time to try it. I replied that I "obviously" did because if I didn't try it then I wouldn't have run into a compilation error and thus would have never asked the question.

Comment: Anyways the reason it wasn't working was because the function you want to run after the AND operator has to return a "truthy" value so that both sides of the command can be run.

Comment: [Returning `0` from the function still allows for the program to continue](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/FAm9fzpOyyZ). Whatever problem you've had is ***not*** with the line of code you've shown.

Comment: My excuses, it simply has to return a value that can be evaluated as a boolean. Either true/false, or 1/0

Comment: There are no booleans in C. And [no, it doesn't need to return a value](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/F7NIlhv7ktC).

Comment: or any number for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int functionToExecute()
{
    printf("ran function");
    return 1;
}

int main() 
{
    int booleanVariable = 1;
    booleanVariable && functionToExecute();
    return 0;
}
```

https://www.mycompiler.io/view/HIbRP3W1uil